# Finding graduate programs supporting a specific research focus

Tags: phd, research-process, graduate-school

I'm looking forward to finding a university that I could do my PhD in computer science in financial systems and machine learning. Financial systems means Foreign Exchange market or Stock markets.

**Is there any way to look for such universities?**

My background:
I studied in three universities in Egypt, USA and Singapore for my bachelor in Comp Eng. Worked in two universities as undergrad research assistant (NTU, Singapore and Uni of Arkansas, US). I won several national and international awards and competitions. Now, I'm working as a junior researcher in north Italy (one year of experience, two by the next fall). And I published 4 papers in last 12 months

Comment: Are we talking US? UK? World? What is your background?

Comment: I'm open to all places. I studied in three universities in Egypt, USA and Singapore for my bachelor in Comp Eng. Worked in two universities as undergrad research assistant (NTU, Singapore and Uni of Arkansas, US). I won several national and international awards and competitions. Now, I'm working as a junior researcher in north Italy (one year of experience, two by the next fall). And I published 4 papers in last 12 months.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.  The actual question _"Are there any way to look for such universities?"_ is applicable to almost anyone interested in a graduate school in a specific topic.

Comment: @Kogesho,, yes?

Comment: Okay @Kogesho , no problem.

Comment: @M-T-A What is your e-mail?

Answer (score 12):

Three easy suggestions:

1. **Look for advisors, not programs.**  It's unlikely that any department is going to have a separate program, or even a separate research group, with your particular focus.   Look for authors of papers that you've read about financial systems and machine learning.  (You *have* read such papers, haven't you?)  Then look at the authors they cite, and the authors that cite them.
2. **Don't limit yourself to computer science departments.**  If you do good research, nobody cares what department is listed on your diploma.  (And if you don't plan to do good research, you don't really want a PhD.)  *Lots* of faculty and students in non-CS departments do excellent computer science research.
3. **Ask your faculty mentors.**  After working at six universities, you've built a large professional academic network; exploit it!  Your faculty colleagues will be considerably more familiar with programs in their (and your) particular focus than Random Strangers on the Internet.